# pipeline could not be constructed: no element "v4l2src" --> gstreamer --> RPI

Tags: android, streaming

I'm using this script to pass audio and video data to my android app :

////////////////////
gst-launch -v v4l2src ! "image/jpeg,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1" ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink host=x.x.x.x port=5000 sync=false alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! 'audio/x-raw- int,rate=8000,width=16,channels=1' ! udpsink host=x.x.x.x port=5001
///////////////////

I installed all neccessery packages but for some unknown reason i get the error in the title. I try to add some other packages but all of them are installed so i have no clue why am getting this error. Maybe some syntax problem ?

Best regards !